# How do I get an parent HTML Tag with Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Test which search for `<span class="legend">`. On a previous level I have a fieldset which contains several values. Here is my problem. I don't get the locator for this fieldset.

First of all I get a list with all `class=legend` objects:

`List<WebElement> groupList = driver.findElements(By.className("legend"));`

This works perfectly, I have a list with several Webelements.

Now I want to iterate this list and save every value from the fieldset of the previous level only. The problem is that Selenium does not find the id of the fieldset.

I tried `tempGroupElement.getAttribute("id")` to get the id but it does not work.

Any idea?

Comment: can't post the HTML part, don't know why. Hope it's enough information.

Answer (score 49):

I have a method for this in C#.

```
public static IWebElement GetParent(IWebElement e)
{
   return e.FindElement(By.XPath(".."));
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. The Xpath is wrong. I tried similar xpaths but they doesn't work too. Thanks for your answer

Comment: What about By.XPath("//.."))?

Comment: I found an other way to solve that problem. The values i need and the legend i need are in one fieldset with `class=info`. So now i can iterate over this WebElement List and get all my values.  
Thanks for any suggestions! :)

Comment: Worked a CHARM for me. Thanks Tadesco.
 - PS: Python Chrome Driver.

Comment: Worked great in node.js / webdriverjs / chrome :)

Comment: which works? ("..") or ("//..")?

Comment: As an extension method: `public static IWebElement GetParent(this IWebElement e)`

Answer (score 14):

You can use `WebElement.findElement(By.xpath("parent::*"))`

I tried, it works in selenium.

Comment: This is my preferred way of doing it.   With the right Xpath locator, you can travel up and down the DOM until you get to what you are looking for.  It's very useful in situations where you want to find a child element with a parent that contains some text (for example).

Comment: Isnt XPath not supported by Safari?

Answer (score 6):

This will create an extension on top of IWebElement that will let you call GetParent directly on the child IWebElement

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IWebElement GetParent(this IWebElement node)
    {
        return node.FindElement(By.XPath(".."));
    }
}
```

Example usage...

```
IWebElement node = WebDriver.FindElement('..');
IWebElement parent = node.GetParent();
```

Comment: Is there something that simple for siblings?

Comment: `FindElement` will throw `NoSuchElementException` if it doesn't find any. IMO it's safer to use `FindElements(By.XPath("..")).SingleOrDefault()`
That way it will return null if nothing is found.
Really wish Selenium support some method like `FindElementIfAny` because sometimes I really don't want an exception thrown.