# Populating a CheckedListBox with extracted labels from a CheckBoxList in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a form that uses Selenium to go to a page and automate tasks for a user. The only part of the page that changes is a CheckBoxList, and I've been trying to extract the labels from it and mirror them to my form's CheckedListBox so users can make the selection there without seeing the page.

So far I have this:

```
        IList<IWebElement> vehicleGroups = Builder.Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("vehGrp"));
        String[] vehicleText = new String[vehicleGroups.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (IWebElement element in vehicleGroups)
        {
            vehicleText[i++] = element.Text;
            vehicleGroupList.Items.Add(element.Text);
        }
```

Which works as far as getting the correct number of elements and populating the form, but all of the labels in vehicleText are blank (or just a space.)

An example of the HTML for one of the labels is

```
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="searchQuery.vehicleGroups[0].isSelected" value="on" class="vehGrp">&nbsp;abcd/efgh ijkl mn (opqrst)</label>
```

Did I miss something or is the " " messing with the label text? The "abcd/efgh ijkl mn (opqrst)" is what I need but it and the potential number of elements can change daily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vehicleGroups` are the `<input>` elements, not the `<label>`s that surround them - and these have no text. This is expected behavior.

You need to get the surrounding `<label>` element, for example using a method like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12194481/7866667

```
var vehicleGroupInputElements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("vehGrp"));
var vehicleGroupNames = vehicleGroupInputElements
    .Select(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("..")))
    .Select(e => e.Text)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Works. Had to change e to f and change some syntax but final result is:

                    var vehicleGroupInputElements = Builder.Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("vehGrp"));
            var vehicleGroupNames = vehicleGroupInputElements.Select(f => f.FindElement(By.XPath(".."))).Select(f => f.Text).ToArray();
            vehicleGroupList.Items.AddRange(vehicleGroupNames);